# How can I create a new control center command?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, control-center

I’d like to enable the users of my app to access one of its features more quickly just by tapping a command in the control center, without the app forced to be in foreground.

I know that I can customize my control center commands, but is it possible to create a new one, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 11, control center commands are **not accessible for third-party apps**. If you want to provide fast access to functions, consider creating a **widget**.